# Using Liquid Haskell to Check for Valid Tokens

Tags: haskell, liquid-haskell

I am doing some experimentation using liquid-haskell to see what kinds of neat things I can do with it and I have hit a bit of a wall. The basic idea is that I have some functions that require an access token that expires after a certain amount of time has passed. I am trying to see how I might use liquid-haskell to ensure that the token is checked for validity before passing it into one of my functions. I have created a minimal working version below that demonstrates my problem. When I run liquid on this file I get the following error:

```
/tmp/liquidTest.hs:18:17-42: Error: Liquid Type Mismatch

 18 | isExpired tok = currTime >= expiration tok
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   Inferred type
     VV : {VV : GHC.Types.Bool | Prop VV <=> Main.currTime >= ?a}

   not a subtype of Required type
     VV : {VV : GHC.Types.Bool | Prop VV <=> currTime >= expiration tok}

   In Context
     Main.currTime := Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime

     tok := Main.Token

     ?a := {?a : Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime | ?a == expiration tok}
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this error is showing up and everything I have tried has failed. Could someone please help me?

Also, I would like to have the currTime function replaced with the getCurrentTime function in the time package. That way I can compare the timestamp on the token with the current time. That would mean that my isExpired function would be of type Token -> IO Bool. Would that even be possible using liquid haskell?

```
import Data.Time
import Language.Haskell.Liquid.Prelude

{-@ data Token = Token
         (expiration :: UTCTime)
@-}

data Token = Token
    { expiration :: UTCTime
    } deriving Show

{-@ measure currTime :: UTCTime @-}
currTime :: UTCTime
currTime = UTCTime (ModifiedJulianDay 57614) 83924.978297

{-@ isExpired :: t:Token -> {v:Bool | ((Prop v) <=> (currTime >= expiration t))} @-}
isExpired :: Token -> Bool
isExpired tok = currTime >= expiration tok

{-@ type ValidToken = {t:Token | currTime < expiration t} @-}

{-@ showToken :: ValidToken -> String @-}
showToken :: Token -> String
showToken tok = show tok

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ct <- getCurrentTime
  let tok = Token ct

  print currTime

  case isExpired tok of
    True -> putStrLn "The token has expired!"
    False -> putStrLn $ showToken tok
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems here.

1. You're trying to define `currTime` as a measure but measures are supposed to be functions. This should be flagged as an error by LiquidHaskell.
2. You may have noticed this before you made `currTime` a measure, but you can't currently refer to top-level definitions in a type signature. We can fix your example by passing `currTime` as a parameter to `isExpired`, and by adding a parameter to the `ValidToken` type (which is probably what you want to do anyway since the validity of the token is with respect to some timestamp). Here's a [link](http://goto.ucsd.edu:8090/index.html#?demo=permalink%2F1471182482_14729.hs) to the working version on our demo page.

Finally, you certainly can rewrite the code to use `getCurrentTime` inside `isValid`, though you'll probably need to change the definition of `ValidToken` since the current time never escapes `isValid`. [Here's](http://goto.ucsd.edu:8090/index.html#?demo=permalink%2F1471183846_14737.hs) how I would do it.

I define an "uninterpreted" measure (no body) called `valid` and change `isExpired`'s type to return `IO {v:Bool | ((Prop v) <=> (not (valid t)))}`. Unfortunately, LiquidHaskell can't verify the definition of `isExpired` because we haven't told it what `valid` means. So we have to `assume` the type for `isExpired`, making it part of our trusted computing base. I'm ok with this because it's a small function, and it's the only thing that needs to be assumed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and the links to the working demos. This is exactly what I needed.